# Header filtering and selecting rows with checkbox column giving back all rows

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm a little bit stumped on why I keep getting a full list of rows back when I do `table.getSelectedData()` when using header filtering.  I have a table containing 16 rows.  I header filter on the email address and get 3 rows.  I then check the select all checkbox in the header and use a button click event to log what is selected.  Whether I use "active", "visible" or nothing I always get 16 rows.

I've tried

```js
cell.getRow().toggleSelect("active");
cell.getRow().toggleSelect("visible");
cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
```

along with

```js
table.getSelectedData("active");
table.getSelectedData("visible");
table.getSelectedData();
```

Table initialization is as follows:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#rules-table", {
    height: 600, 
    data:tabledata,  
    layout:"fitColumns",
    persistentSort:true,
    selectable:true,
    selectablePersistence:false,
    pagination:"local", 
    movableColumns: true,  
    columns:[  
        {title:"UUID",        field:"uuid",        headerFilter:"input", frozen:true, width:300},
        {title:"Type",        field:"type",        headerFilter:"input", width:100},
        {title:"SubType",     field:"subtype",     headerFilter:"input", width:100},
        {title:"AssetUUID",   field:"asset_uuid",  headerFilter:"input", width:300},
        {title:"Info",        field:"info",        headerFilter:"input"},
        {title:"Owner",       field:"owner",       headerFilter:"input", width:200},
        {formatter:"rowSelection", titleFormatter:"rowSelection", align:"center", width:20, headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){
                cell.getRow().toggleSelect("active");
        }},
        {formatter:printIcon, width:0, align:"center", width:26, headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){generate_assets_options_menu(e, cell)}}
            
    ],
});
```

So to describe a little more, I then do some header filtering to whittle down the rows, select the rows i want, and using a button to get selected rows for a DB delete operation.  Everything works fine if I manually select specific rows.

However when I whittle down using the header filters and click the header checkbox to select all visible rows (let's say there's 3 after filtering), when I print out what has been selected I always get everything i.e. 16 rows.

The delete button click event as follows :

```js
var selectedData = table.getSelectedData("active");
var selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows("active");
    
console.log(selectedData);
console.log(selectedRows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***getSelectedData*** function returns all selected rows, regardless of whether they are currently filtered or not.

By default a selected row that is filtered out remains selected and when the filter is removed and the row reappears it will still be selected.

If you want to see only the rows that have been filtered and are selected, i would suggest that you use the ***getRows*** function to get an array of active row components. and then use a filter function on the array to get the filtered selected rows:

```
var rows = table.getRows("active");

var selectedRows = rows.filter(function(row){
    return row.isSelected();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Oli, I guess I assumed setting the header checkbox might work alongside the filtering and only select what was active but this worked a treat for me.  Small note for anyone else looking for the solution, I had to call table.getRows instead of table.getRow to get the array of rows.

Comment: I have amended the answer to fix the typo. If you thought this was a useful answer please mark it as the answer so others can find it

Answer (score 0):

So my final solution to (to retrieve a set of uuids in this case) which have been filtered down with header filtering, and then selected with the "check all" checkbox is as follows

```
    var rule_uuids = [];
    var rows = table.getRows("active");

    var selectedRows = rows.filter(function(row){
        return row.isSelected();
    });

    selectedRows.forEach(function (item) {                          
        rule_uuids.push(item._row.data.uuid);               
    });
```

Thanks again Oli